# Spark(Standalone) didnot execute my job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jobs, shuffle

Alive Workers: 4
Cores in use: 16 Total
Memory in use: 27.2 GB Total

**My driver program:**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
sc = SparkContext()


image_list = []
init_weight = 1 / (const.POSITIVE_SAMPLES_NUMBER * 2)
sample_type = True

acc_sample_count = sc.accumulator(-1)

samp_list = []
index = 0
for image_name in os.listdir(const.POSITIVE_SAMPLES_PATH):
    image = Image.open(const.POSITIVE_SAMPLES_PATH+image_name)
    image_resize = image.resize((24, 24), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image_gray_format = preoperate.format_gray(array(image_resize))
    image_list.append([index ,image_gray_format])
    index += 1

image_rdd = sc.parallelize(image_list, 128).setName('image_rdd')

samples_rdd = image_rdd.map(lambda img_index : generate_sample(img_index[1], sample_type, init_weight, img_index[0])).setName('sample_rdd')
samples_list = samples_rdd.collect()
print('#######################################')
print(sys.getsizeof(samples_list))
bc_samples = sc.broadcast(samples_list)
del samples_list
image_rdd.unpersist()
y2_position_rdd = sc.parallelize(const.Y2_POSITION, 2000)
y2_fea_val_rdd = y2_position_rdd.mapPartitions(lambda pos : map_cal(pos, bc_samples.value, haarcal.haar_like_Y2_cal), 2000).persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
take_list = y2_fea_val_rdd.take(1)
print('#####################################')
for sample in take_list[0][1]:
    print(sample.index)
print('#####################################')
print(y2_fea_val_rdd.count())
```

Here are two jobs:
The first job it works well, but the secend job was ignored without any log.
stderr in web ui without any err logs

**My log:**

```
17/03/11 16:49:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 115.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 115) in 1463 ms on 10.29.90.41 (executor 3) (116/128)
```

17/03/11 16:49:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 116.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 116) in 1469 ms on 10.30.147.199 (executor 9) (117/128)

17/03/11 16:49:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 117.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 117) in 1380 ms on 10.30.147.84 (executor 13) (118/128)

17/03/11 16:49:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 119.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 119) in 1376 ms on 10.30.147.84 (executor 12) (119/128)

17/03/11 16:49:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 118.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 118) in 1410 ms on 10.30.147.154 (executor 4) (120/128)

17/03/11 16:49:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 120.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 120) in 1495 ms on 10.30.147.154 (executor 7) (121/128)

17/03/11 16:49:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 122.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 122) in 1355 ms on 10.30.147.154 (executor 6) (122/128)

17/03/11 16:49:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 123.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 123) in 1424 ms on 10.30.147.84 (executor 14) (123/128)

17/03/11 16:49:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 121.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 121) in 1566 ms on 10.30.147.199 (executor 8) (124/128)

17/03/11 16:49:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 124.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 124) in 1342 ms on 10.30.147.154 (executor 5) (125/128)

17/03/11 16:49:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 125.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 125) in 1344 ms on 10.29.90.41 (executor 0) (126/128)

17/03/11 16:49:34 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 126.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 126) in 1599 ms on 10.30.147.199 (executor 11) (127/128)

17/03/11 16:49:35 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 127.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 127) in 2667 ms on 10.29.90.41 (executor 2) (128/128)

17/03/11 16:49:35 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool

17/03/11 16:49:35 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (collect at /home/dcooo/projects/FaceDetection/main/facedetection/spark_cal_features.py:70) finished in 16.419 s

17/03/11 16:49:35 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: collect at 
/home/dcooo/projects/FaceDetection/main/facedetection/spark_cal_features.py:70, took 17.078753 s

#

40816

17/03/11 16:49:37 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook

17/03/11 16:49:37 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.165.51.174:4040

17/03/11 16:49:37 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors

17/03/11 16:49:37 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down

17/03/11 16:49:37 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: 
MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!

17/03/11 16:49:37 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared

17/03/11 16:49:37 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped

17/03/11 16:49:37 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped

17/03/11 16:49:37 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!

17/03/11 16:49:37 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext

17/03/11 16:49:37 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called

17/03/11 16:49:37 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-e8666f9e-c811-48f1-b116-7b48cd74347a

17/03/11 16:49:37 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-e8666f9e-c811-48f1-b116-7b48cd74347a/pyspark-a74f8c26-c7ef-43ed-ad5e-100a7e4c57e5

My first job works well, and spark didnot execute my second job
**My environments:**

```
spark.executor.cores 1
```

spark.cores.max 16

spark.executor.memory 1g

spark.default.parallelism 128